# Netlogo giving attribute value of agent based on value of patch and slider parameter

Tags: slider, patch, netlogo

I want to give income attribute to agent which is based on patch value where the agent stays and slider parametre.

```
 to setup
   if pcolor = yellow
   [sprout-resident 1
   [set color sky
   set shape "default"
   set size 1
   set-income
   ask patch-here [set pcolor brown
                set landuse "resident"
                set is-bought? TRUE
                set owner [who] of myself]]]
   end

  to set-income
  ifelse land-price > buycapabilityhigh(this is the slider parametr) [set income "high"]
  [ifelse land-price < buycapabilitymiddlle and land-price > buycapabilitylow [set income "middle"]
  [if land-price < buycapabilitylow [set income "low"]]]
  end
```

so I want to give agent category high middle low income based on land price where the agent stays and based on buycapability which is set by slider. Please help giving advice to code this kind of mechanism. Thanks

Comment: 1. What problem are you running into?  What happens when you `ask turtles [set-income]`?  2. Just use a sequence of if statements; no need for nesting.

Comment: Agree, your code looks fine. If you're having some difficulty or problem with it, you need to tell us what it is.

Comment: oh ya.. I'm sorry for being not detail, when I run this code, this to-set-income makes all income attribute of agents becoming "low". Even tough land-price of an agent patch is greater than its buycapability of agent ,which should make the income attribute "high", the income attribute remain "low". So, I dont know wheter do I have to be more specific or restate in this to-se-income that the patch that I mean is the one that there is resident on it (I'm trying this alternative but still haven't found the right code/ I don't know how to code it) or what.. please help giving advice for this..

Comment: If there are only three categories (high, middle, and low), why do you have three thresholds? Shouldn't two thresholds be sufficient to distinguish between three categories? One for the threshold between low and middle, and one for the threshold between middle and high.

Comment: @SethTisue I still can't figure out how to make it to two thresholds, please kindly explain more. For example low threshold <50,  50<middle<100, high > 100 that's why I create 3 sliders to represent it.

Comment: @SethTisue yes, your right, I've just figured it out..I have made it to two sliders but it still produces the same result, all agent attributes are "low". what do you think that might wrong with the code?

Comment: Please update your question to include your current code.

Answer (score -1):

Is the variable `land-price` a patch's attributes ?
If it is, then I think the problems is in your `set-income` function.

You should use `[land-price] of patch-here` instead of just `land-price` in the if-statement.

Moreover, just like Alan said. you could just use a sequence of if statements.
it goes like this

```
if [land-price] of patch-here > ... [...]
if [land-price] of patch-here < ... and ... [...]
if [land-price] of patch-here < ... [...]
```

Comment: yes... land-price is a patch's attribute and buycapability is agent's attribute. What about the buycapability?do I need to add something?
I've tried your suggestion but it seem still did'nt work.
      `to set-income
       ifelse [land-price] of patch-here > buycapabilityhigh [set income "high"]
  [ifelse [land-price] of patch-here < buycapabilitymiddlle and [land-price] of patch-here > buycapabilitylow [set income "middle"]
  [if [land-price] of patch-here < buycapabilitylow [set income "low"]]]
  end`

Comment: I am sorry, I mean buycapability is the slider parameter which will determine agent's attribut income wheter high, mid or low based on the land-price where the agents stand, lower, in between or greater than certain buycapability paramter value.

Comment: I also have used if statement, not ifelse but the result is still same. Please help to find my mistakes.

Comment: `[land-price] of patch-here` is synonymous with simply writing `land-price`. A turtle has direct access to the variables of the patch it is standing on.

Comment: I see, I didn't know that, thank you for correcting me Seth Tisue. and sorry for not being useful.

Comment: so. there are 3 sliders?

Comment: yes, there are 3 sliders... it's oke @M.R. Murazza I also just know that.

Comment: @M.R.Murazza so, do you have any idea what probably wrong with the code?